# Damage and insult//injury

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play [Insult](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426915), then attack with my 4/4 and my opponent blocks with their 4/4.
Do both creatures die?  Damage cannot be prevented, does that work both ways?

Comment: What do you mean by "attack my opponent's 4/4 with my 4/4"? What do you target with Insult or Injury? Do you cast Injury immediately after Insult?

Comment: Insult//injury is a sorcery, played before combat

Comment: During the combat phase I attack with my 4/4 and they block with their 4/4.

Comment: Do both 4/4's die or just theirs beacause my damage is not prevented because I cast the spell?  I am just using the insult portion of the card.

Comment: Great, many thanks.  That is what I thought, just checking

Comment: I think you're misreading Insult or something... there's no damage prevention in the scenario you mention. Insult says that damage cannot be prevented, which means that if someone plays a damage prevention effect, it won't work. But in your scenario, Insult doesn't actually do anything relevant (other than deal 8 damage instead of 4 which doesn't matter).

Comment: As a note, if you cast Injury from the graveyard immediately after Insult, the damage on Injury would be doubled, so you could kill the 4/4 and deal 4 damage to the opponent with the spell, and then attack with your 4/4 to deal 8 more damage.

Answer (score 9):

As [GendoIkari](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/2602/gendoikari) mentioned in a comment, the way you've asked your question makes me wonder if you may misinterpreting what [Insult](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInsult%5d) does. It does two things:

- Stops damage from being prevented this turn, if anything would otherwise prevent damage
- Doubles damage dealt by sources you control, if any source you control would deal damage

Without Insult's effects, when you attack with your 4/4 creature and your opponent blocks with their 4/4, your creature would deal 4 damage to theirs and theirs would deal 4 damage to yours, killing both. But what actually happens instead, taking into account Insult's effects, is this:

- Insult stops damage from being prevented, but nothing is preventing any damage, so that effect doesn't do anything
- Insult doubles damage dealt by sources you control, so the 4 damage your creature would deal to your opponent's is doubled to 8

Thus your creature deals 8 damage to your opponent's, and your opponent's creature deals 4 damage to yours, meaning that they both die.

Insult's first effect, which stops damage prevention, is only relevant if someone plays a spell like [Djeru's Resolve](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDjeru%27s%5d%2b%5bResolve%5d), controls a permanent like [Protection of the Hekma](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProtection%20of%20the%20Hekma%5d), or activates an ability like the +1 loyalty ability on [Gideon, Ally of Zendikar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Ally%20of%20Zendikar%5d). All of these may normally cause some damage to be prevented, which you can tell because they include the phrase "prevent...damage".<sup>1</sup> Insult stops these kinds of damage prevention effects from working.

---

<sup>1</sup>It can happen that damage is prevented without something explicitly saying "prevent...damage", such as with the protection ability, but I don't believe any recent cards (current Standard) have that ability.

Answer (score 4):

The damage prevention portion works both ways, but only your sources deal double damage.

If you play Insult, then attack with your 4/4, and he blocks with his 4/4, you will deal 8 damage to his creature, and he will deal 4 damage to your creature.

So both creatures die.